# Wildfly Failed to Load Module for Oracle Driver

Tags: oracle, jdbc, wildfly, oracle12c, wildfly-10

I'm attempting to add an Oracle DB datasource to Wildfly 10. Here's what I have:

```
<wildfly-home>\modules\com\oracle\ojdbc6\main\
                                              module.xml
                                              ojdbc6.jar
```

**module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:Wildfly:module:1.0" name="com.oracle.ojdbc6">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="ojdbc6.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.resource.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/> <!-- See * below -->
   </dependencies>
</module>
```

* I have tried both with and without the line `<module name="javax.transaction.api/>`. Some examples I've found online include it. Some do not. It seems to make no difference with whether the error occurs or not.

**ojdbc6.jar** was copied from `<oracle-home>\jdbc\lib\ojdbc6.jar`.

I have modified `<wildfly-home>\standalone\configuration\standalone.xml` to include this within the `<drivers>` tag:

```
<driver name="oraclethin" module="com.oracle.ojdbc6">
    <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
</driver>
```

This error message is being spat out when I `cd` into `<wildfly-home>\bin` and run `.\standalone.bat`:

```
15:17:13,415 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("jdbc-driver" => "oraclethin")
]) - failure description: "WFLYJCA0041: Failed to load module for driver [com.oracle.ojdbc6]"
```

I've triple checked the spelling on everything. I've tried taking out some lines (and putting them back when nothing changes). Is anyone seeing what I'm missing?

Comment: Are you sure that it should be wildfly and not jboss in "urn:wildfly:module:1.0"?

Comment: You have a typo in `xmlns="urn:Wildfly:module:1.0"` but I'm not sure that's the issue (Wildfly vs wildfly).  Can you post a full log of what happens when you start?

Comment: @user140547 - The documentation I'm following definitely said `urn:Wildfly:module:1.0`, but you're right, changing it to `urn:jboss:module:1.0` appears to have fixed it. I'll submit a doc defect. Post as an answer so I can mark it correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0"`

As described in https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODULES/Module+descriptors

Comment: In my case I'm using the official Keycloak Docker image which already contains a `module.xml` file which does use `urn:jboss:module:1.0`, so in theory you should only have to place the jar in the correct path... unfortunately this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

what solve the issue for me was to enlarge the timeout connection on the standalone.xml file on jboss

```
<system-properties>
...
        <property name="jboss.as.management.blocking.timeout" value="6000"/>
    </system-properties>
```

Comment: Where should this be placed inside the standalone.xml?